# EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on 10.6.8

Tags: xcode, macos

I am trying to get my app to run on version 10.6 but when I do I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. When I run it on my computer which has the latest version it runs fine, but for some reason it won't work on versions below 7. Since I don't develop on a 10.6 computer all I have to look at is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87604930 CFDictionaryGetValue + 96
1   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff810814d9 CFHTTPCookieCreateWithProperties +         111
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88812f4c -[NSHTTPCookie initWithProperties:]     + 29
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88813243 +[NSHTTPCookie     cookieWithProperties:] + 50
```

This is the main part of the crash log. It seems to crash trying to get a dictionary value but I'm not exactly sure how to read these.

Comment: Start from the bottom in order to read that call stack; it appears that you're making some type of a `NSHTTPCookie` call. The `CFDictionaryGetValue` call is being made in the `CFHTTPCookieCreateWithProperties` call which is made in the next call so on down the stack. Somewhere (probably lower down the stack), you are making a call that may not adhere to non-ARC standards, because I believe that lower OSX versions do not implement ARC. This is just a guess. Try seeing if you are calling a method on an improperly retained object.

Comment: Thanks I'll look and let you know

Answer (score 2):

Okay I was able to solve it. I loaded a cookie on start with a method like this:

```
- (NSHTTPCookie *)loadCookie {
    NSDictionary *properties = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kDefCookie];
    return [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties[COOKIE_KEY]];
}
```

I saved the cookie properties in defaults so I could save the users cookie across sessions. Running on the latest version, this method returned nil for me when there was no cookie stored in defaults. For some reason this doesn't seem to work on 10.6. I changed the method like this and it works perfectly now.

```
- (NSHTTPCookie *)loadCookie {
    NSDictionary *properties = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kDefCookie];
    if (properties)
        return [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties[COOKIE_KEY]];
    else return nil;
}
```

Thanks Carter Pape fo helping me read the crash log. I focused to much on the cfDictionary part and I didn't read the stuff that came before